Is kaliyuga actually bad right now?
It is said that there is a lot of sin in today's age Kaliyuga, where murder, rape and other sins are seen everyday. Humans are dying everydays, etc.
But the condition for humans was same throughout all yugas, am I wrong?
Asuras use to kill Brahmins and eat them all the time, the kings used to do as they please, they used to kill other kings and forcefully take their wives and wars were being waged every day.
Compared to that, there's a lot of peace  in today's society. Racism has also decreased and even lower castes are allowed to compete and walk in temples.
Old kings used to differentiate a lot.
So, are there more sins today or was these much sins always present?

Sins were present earlier, it's just gotten worse now.

It is said that there is a lot of sin in today's age Kalyug, where murder, rape and other sins are seen everyday. Humans are dying everydays, etc. But the condition for humans was same throughout all yugas, am I wrong?
Dharma is a Spectrum of choices that one can choose to act. The highest choice is called Dharmic choice, and the lower the choice the worse the Adharma.
So, the choices made by the kings, Brahmins (knowledge class), and commoners in those days (other Yugas) was high, compared to this yuga. Not that Adharma didn't exist. Otherwise, there was no need for Sri Maha Vishnu to take Avataras.
Kali Yuga can also exist as per location and time as per Mahabharatam Itihasa. Meaning, Desham (location) and Kaalam (timeframe/age) both have Yugas. In this sense today, many countries are experiencing Kali Yuga and others might be experiencing Satya/Treta/Dwapara yuga.
When it comes Time (Kaala) the movement of Sun (which also travels in space within its own galaxy determines Yuga, As per that we are entering Dwapara Yuga.
As per Puranas, we are still in the first paada (step) of Kali Yuga.
As per the renowned scholar Sri Chaganti once said, Sri Krishna did many Lilas (acts devoid of Karma). Lila = playful acts. Out of that people in Kali yuga are more interested and discuss his Chora-lila (acts of thief) during the day and Raasa-lila (acts of divine ecstasy, esp. involving women). This was not the case for the general public during other yugas. So, in Kali yuga, people are more interested in Intoxication, pleasure food, wealth accumulation, and erotic endeavor.
